Do you know any siddhi purushas or Gurus who have clairvioance and can speak with devatas?
I have some questions regarding personal issue I want to meet a siddhi purusha or a genuine tantrik or a person who can power to converse with devatas..And who is not too busy attending to lot of people..as i may need to contact Him/Her frequently..its very urgent..
Please respond
